# Tricky factorial in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, factorial, fixpoint-combinators

Is there is a way to create function to calculate factorial in Haskell, using the following function:

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible. In fact it's a pretty standard thing. Care to show any research effort on your own part?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I know how to calculate factorial in a different way, but it is kind of confusing to do it with function ''fix''

Comment: Have  you considered to use the following [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator)?

Comment: The article @RodrigoRibeiro mentions even has a specific example for factorial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#The_factorial_function

Comment: @RodrigoRibeiro Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To be original

```
fac = (fix ((1:) . zipWith (*) [1..]) !!)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The trivial way:

```
factorial = fix go 1 where
  go f acc n = fact acc n
```

Where `fact acc n === acc * n!`. This is, of course, an altogether ridiculous definition.

Can you see how to modify the ridiculous definition so that it uses the `f` parameter? This will, hopefully, mimic the structure of the explicitly recursive definition you've already written.